# .ogg and .webm video file not playing in firefox 6 through html5 video tag

Tags: html, firefox6, html5-video

here below are my codes i used:

The page works fine on Google Chrome, Safari and Opera browser but i cant get the video to play in firefox 6 and IE 9. can anyone please say what is wrong? I thought that .ogg file is compatible with firefox but still the video dont play at all.

here is my site: http://pages.intnet.mu/taoravi

Answer (score 0):

Check the server headers:

> It's worth re-emphasizing for the time being, that if the MIME types for Theora video are not set on the server, the video may not show or show a gray box containing an X (if JavaScript is enabled).

from https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTML/Element/Video#Server_support

Comment: is there any other way? since i dont have access to the "mime.types" file  on the server i use.

Comment: Other than providing a Flash player alternative for Firefox or changing the video's encoding, I don't know of a workaround. If you can edit the directory's .htaccess file you can set the mime type there.

Comment: yeha it seem that the directory dont have a .htaccess file and when i do try putting one up there. it just disappear after upload! dont really why this is so though! :(